# What would be a valid replacement of "as"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrasing

Say I want to write something to say:

> John looked over his shoulder as he opened the door slowly.

However, for stylistic reasons I don't really want to use *as* in that sentence. There must be other ways of expressing simultaneity. What words or phrasing could replace the *as* in that sentence?

The [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here says

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

... so please **explain** your choice and **why** your suggestion works [e.g. its grammar] as that introduces some objective measure of validity.

Comment: *While* can serve; the sentence is better with *as* though.

Comment: Why do you want to replace it?

Comment: One possible reason to replace it is that *as* can mean *because* (although that doesn't really apply to *opened* and would require *had opened*). That temporal distinction could make for a question in its own right.

Comment: Hmm. I should have read the question more carefully. I **hope** the question is now more on-topic, although I'm prepared to find that others may disagree.

Answer (score 3):

The adverb makes 'he opened the door slowly' non-punctive. It is not clear whether 'looked' is describing a punctive act or a durative one.

If the former (the apparent tautology is idiomatic):

> John opened the door slowly, taking a swift glance over his shoulder
>   as he did so. /
>
> John took a swift glance over his shoulder as he slowly opened the
>   door.

If the latter:

> John opened the door slowly, all the while looking back over his shoulder.

Comment: You seem to be using *punctive* to mean at a point in time, *vs* its OED1 def., “Making straight for a
point”.  Note, [onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=punctive) and [wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=punctive&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) don't find *punctive* in the several dozen dictionaries they search.

Comment: After say Paczynski (file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/DAD/My%20Documents/Downloads/abstractbook2010-final.pdf) [p 23]: 
Thus it has been proposed that it is the placement of a 
punctive verb (such as pounce or squeak) within a durative context (such as for several 
minutes or throughout the afternoon) that results in the multiple-event interpretation, a 
phenomenon called aspectual coercion.... Within each vignette, the second 
sentence contained an introductory context that was punctive (after several minutes), 
durative (for several minutes) or explicitly iterative (several times).

Comment: M Lynne Murphy, in ['Lexical Meaning'](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=o3g5dMofckgC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=punctive+meaning&source=bl&ots=oBuqFeASPV&sig=h67cd9NMs8NAGwytLomkV8dE3Zc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4FrRU9C5NZOe7AbNsICwBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=punctive%20meaning&f=false) actually defines the word for events rather than the associated verbs: "Events that happen in a moment are said to be punctual (or ... punctive), while longer ones ... are durative"

Answer (score 1):

Most linking conjunctions you could use here will sound a little clunky. I'm guessing what you're aiming to show is the simultaneity of the two actions. A participle clause would achieve this effect without the need for an extra conjunction. You could turn either clause into a participle clause, so either of the following would do:

> - Looking over his shoulder, John slowly opened the door.
> - Slowly opening the door, John looked over his shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

Opening the door slowly, John looked over his shoulder.

Comment: This example is correct, but does not really answer the question, as Spectre is looking for an alternative to "as".

Comment: ... Which question? 'What words ... could replace the as ...?' or the implied one: 'However, for stylistic reasons I don't really want to use _as_ in that sentence. There must be other ways of expressing simultaneity.... please explain your choice and why your suggestion works [eg its grammar]' (which obviously envisions a possible rewrite as OP is happy with the grammar of the original). The fundamental question being asked here is about **ways of expressing simultaneity**. This is a perfectly valid suggestion; it is not a full answer as it makes no attempt to explain the semantics / syntax.

Comment: There isn't any "alternative to _as_". What a silly idea. Words are not replaceable beads on a string. They are all unique, with unique history, unique affordances, prohibitions, and requirements, a unique set of idioms and constructions, and a unique blend of meanings and uses. If, for stylistic reasons, one doesn't wish to use it, one has other options; otherwise one would not have any stylistic reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> John looked over his shoulder and slowly opened the door.

**And** is simplest of all when combining things, even actions.

Answer (score 1):

Replacement of terms doesn't always have to be the answer.

For example, you could omit "as" and rearrange the sentence as follows:

"Opening the door slowly, John looked over his shoulder."

If you want it left in its original order, you can replace "as he" with "and," as seen below:

"John looked over his shoulder and opened the door slowly."

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternative constructions:

> "John looked over his shoulder, at the same time slowly opening the door."
>
> "While slowly opening the door, John looked over his shoulder."
>
> "John looked over his shoulder, slowly opening the door as he did so."
>
> "John looked over his shoulder, slowly opening the door in the meantime."
>
> "John looked over his shoulder, all the while slowly opening the door."

Answer (score -2):

''While'' is a better replacement as both of the words explains doing something simultaneously.

Comment: _While_ is a **possible** replacement. Not a better replacement. In fact, it feels distinctly inferior to _as_ in this case.